# Is there a standard for naming foreign keys when two columns reference the same table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key

I've always used the name `FK_CurrentTableName_ReferencedTableName`. I just ran into a situation where I've got a table with `CreatedById` and `ModifiedById` both pointing to the same (users) table, so this naming convention won't work.

Is it actually better to change all my reference constraints to `FK_CurrentTableName_CurrentColumnName`? Or should I keep it the same unless there is a conflict and then do `FK_CurrentTableName_CurrentColumnName_ReferencedTableName` or `FK_CurrentTableName_ReferencedTableName_CurrentColumnName`?

I've searched and read contradictory opinions. For SQL Server, is there a standard?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no standard naming convention for this or just about any other scenario. Naming conventions are purely subjective: that *your* convention makes sense, and that you use *your* standard consistently, are both **much** more important than which standard you choose.

That said, in this case, I would opt for this option:

```
FK_CurrentTable_Created_Users
FK_CurrentTable_Modified_Users
```

This provides all the information you would need if you wanted to deduce something about this foreign key without all the difficult labor of retrieving the actual definition. If you just use this:

```
FK_CurrentTable_Created
```

Then you don't get any information about the other table. In this specific case it should be easy enough to infer, but that won't always be true. If you use this:

```
FK_CurrentTable_Users_Created
```

That just feels to me like it's in the wrong order. "This table references that table on column x." Much more intuitive, IMHO, to say "This table's column x references that table." It might even call for full references on both sides (of course, the users table may have more than one candidate key, though it is fairly uncommon for an FK to point to a candidate/natural rather than the surrogate):

```
FK_CurrentTable_Created_Users_UserID
```

And therein lies the problem. You're going to continue finding contradictory opinions precisely because this decision has to, by definition, be driven by opinion. And not everyone is going to agree.

Answer (score 4):

Some random thoughts, there are probably many standards out there, but none is globally accepted as the standard. I agree with Aaron that whatever you decide, stick with it through the project.

The naming conventions depend on a lot of things, the DBMS being one. The name of the constraint is sometime unique within the table, sometime unique withing the database, perhaps some product treat it unique within the schema.

For DB2 LUW (which is the DBMS I use the most) the name is unique within a table (same name can be reused between tables). The name of the constraint that is violated is often truncated in the error message and what table it concerns is often obvious. It is also quite common to have foreign keys that contain several columns. I therefor use the following convention:

- PK_[TABLE]         -- primary key constraint
- AKn_[TABLE]        -- alternative key, unique constraint
- Cn_[TABLE]         -- check constraint
- FKn_[PARENT_TABLE] -- foreign key constraint

Slightly off topic, but for triggers:

- IRBn_[TABLE]       -- Insert, Row, Before
- DRAn_[TABLE]       -- Delete, Row, After
- USAn_[TABLE]       -- Update, Statement, After

and so fourth.

I don't know SQL Server well enough to give you any advise there, but hopefully you will get some ideas on different considerations.